# Does the AWS Amplify push package up the entire node_modules folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, amazon-gateway

When we run `amplify push` does `amplify` package up the entire `node_modules` folder, or is that recreated on the AWS side using package.json?

Also asked this question here:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/4018

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed with the AWS Amplify team that it does.  I made a mistake in my intall.

Instead of `@fireflysemantics/stripe` I installed `@fireflysemantics/slice`.  And thus the import:

```
const stripeapi = require('@fireflysemantics/stripe')
```

Failed, causing the lambda function to fail.